# Find extrema or saddle point when the second derivative test fails

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Quick question.  For a student's practice exam, he needs to determine whether $(0,0)$ is a min/max/saddlept/none for:

$$
f(x,y)=x^2y-y^3
$$

The second derivative test fails, and I don't recognize the form of the surface.  Is there any way to classify $(0,0)$ without looking at the graph?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0$ be arbitrary.
$$f(0,\varepsilon)=-\varepsilon^3<0\\
f(0,-\varepsilon)=\varepsilon^3>0$$
implies that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point.